# Whats a good number of villagers to aim for having in Age of Empires 3?

Tags: pc, age-of-empires-iii

When playing both Campain and Skirmish, the Computer(s) always seem to have at least 10 villagers on food garthering alone, and they always seem to have lot more doing just about everything.

I tend to have a small number, maybe 10 total, and often find im running low on resource until i get about 10 or 20 villagers on mills (then i use the market to get most of my needed resource)

Does anyone have any advice on how many i should have in general?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can never have enough villagers in Age of Empires. Early game you should be making a villager at all times. By late game, you should have somewhere between 30-50 villagers.

With that many villagers, you will have a ton of resources, which will allow you to mass produce everything, to the point where you can have 4 production buildings going at once, during a battle to send in reinforcements.

Answer (score 0):

villagers are important try to have at least 50 villager in later stages of game 20 working on 2 mills 20 on 2  plantation and ten gathering wood.
plantation and mills upgrade are important make sure you have upgraded it too full before declaring a full scale war against any other country. By this you will never run out of any resources

Answer (score 0):

This question really depends on who you are playing as. For most European civilizations, you want around no more than sixty. However, the Ottomans generally put their auto-generation cap at fourty-five because the next one is way too high, and the germans simply max out their settler wagons. Native American Civilization Need more because of the fire pit, and often have 75-95. Asian civilizations also need more due to the lack of factories, but the Japanese May have more or less depending on how many shines they can max out. It really depends on the Civilization.